# How to remove rectangle outline from image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I wrote some short program which draw a rectangle on image and then after press key shift to right and draw again. The result is that I receive a lot of rectangles on image but I want to draw only one rectangle, press key and draw new shifted rectangle without the previous. What can I do? Maybe there is any function which remove previous cvrectangle??To draw rectangle I use:

```
cv::rectangle( src,
               cvPoint(x,y),
               cvPoint(x+50,y+50),
               CV_RGB(10,10,10), 5, 8
             );
```

Comment: You'll probably have to redraw the background image every time and then draw the rectangle over it.

Comment: Which of these is your question - how to draw a single rectangle for every keystroke (ignore multiple registrations of a keypress), or how to draw a rectangle moving in different frames?

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep your original image, do not modify it by drawing on it.
2. Create a second image, with the same size as the first image.
3. To draw your rectangle:
   3.1 Draw your entire original image into your second image.
   3.2 Draw your rectanble into your second image.
   3.3 Draw your second image to the screen or save it to a fine or do with it what you like.

Everytime that you draw a new rectangle, restart steps 3.1 to 3.3
This way you will only see one rectangle at a time.

Good luck and have fun! : )